# file encryption that root cannot read

Tags: encryption

I have regular user access to a friend's root server. I can put my data there and he (as a normal user) could not read my data, but with the root account he could.

If I use something like en encrypted home folder, he could still read the data when I am logged in. Is there some way to protect the data in a way that only I can read it and not root?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Encrypt the data on your computer, then send it to his.  You can use `gpg` for this.  If you want to be able to log on to his computer and access the files, then no, there is nothing you can do to prevent root from spying on you; if you don't trust the computer, then you can not use it to handle sensitive information.

Answer (score 1):

You can use some software to encrypt data.
Two most popular choice are

- [AES crypt](http://www.aescrypt.com/)
- [TrueCrypt](http://www.truecrypt.org/)

TrueCrypt is very advanced tool. It also allow you to create virtual encrypted devices.

Both are freely available.

Comment: I think my question is not clear enough. I know about these tools. The problem is, whenever I mount such an encrypted volume, root would potentially have access to that mounted partition. How would I prevent that?

Comment: Are you talking about mounting them locally on that root server -- or remotely from your machine?

Comment: That is kind of my question. Locally mounting it probably no option, but I do not know a tool for mounting it remotely.